# Applescript to upload open file to web page

Tags: applescript

I want an easier way to get files into my intranet.  I open a file, like a PDF or Word file.  When I figure out what it is (say someone has emailed it to me), I want to click something that causes the following actions:

```
1) My web browser opens and goes to my intranet Add File page  
2) In the form, there is a file upload box
3) The file is in that box so I don`t need to navigate to it.
```

Per the comment below, here is what the HTML form looks like (although I am not aware of a a different way to do it):

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File to upload: <input type="file">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Just in case you care, here are more details:  Using Mac OSX (hence, Applescript), browser is Safari.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what have you tried,what browser do you use, what the html form look like...... i could go on and on here.... you need to ask questions about code not i need to do a bunch of stuff can you show me how to do it all

Comment: I have not tried anything.  I have not thought o of a way to simplify it.  The html form looks like any other form that has html. I will edit the question to add that, although I am not aware of any special condition that makes one form's file input box different than another.  Voting my question down I think is unfair.  Frequently answers are far worse, only pointing in a general direction.  If this is the standard, then most questions should be voted down in the double digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few things your gonna need to sort out.

1. First: you need to figure where you
       want to trigger this code from. You
       could write a script and put it in
       the script menu for easy access. But
       that does solve how your going to
       find out where the file lives
       because your gonna need that to put
       it into the form. if your always
       going to do it from mail then you
       only have to target mail but if you
       want to do it from word and acrobat
       and however many apps then you have
       allot more code to right.

   2 Safari isn't all that scriptable but
   you certainly can open a url see
   [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314901/how-to-read-a-file-and-open-safari-with-the-read-result-with-mac-applescript/3318215#3318215)  to see how but
   then you will need to run javascript
   in the applescript to set the value
   of file form to the location of the
   file

**To Answer Some Questions**

all thee apps in question use different commands to get the file path and when it comes to mail app it's more complicated because you have to look at the attachments of the message and figure out which one you want and then get its path. AND then preview isn't' scriptable and powerpoint I'm not sure will give you the file path.

here are two examples of file path

```
tell application "Microsoft Word" to set thepath to get path of document 1
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro" to set thepath to file alias of document 1

set thepath to posix path of thepath -- this will make it /path/to/file
```

so once you have "thepath" then you run JavaScript to set the value of the file input to "thepath"

hope that all makes sense

Comment: This is helpful.  On 1), is there a way generically (meaning cross-application) to figure out where the file lives?  Say we limit it to Word, Acrobat, PowerPoint, and Preview.  Note that most of the files will be coming through mail. On 2), I could do that if need be.  I don't know how to refer to the file and refer to it.

Comment: It does.  Seems like I'm headed down the wrong path.  Let me try another route.  What about dragging the file to a folder and attaching a folder action.  Specifically, if you had to do this in the fewest steps, what would you do (generically -- I'm not asking you to code it for me).  Thanks again.

Comment: @mcgrailm Have you tried your suggestion and gotten it to work, taken a POSIX path and set a form field to it? I've tried this in Chrome without luck: execute javascript ("document.getElementById('FileField').value = '" & fileSelectedinFinder & "'")

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer, which I hadn't thought possible:

You can drag and drop an attachment from an email onto the "CHOOSE FORM" form field in a form for a web page.  It works.  Put your email window on the left of the screen.  Put your web page on the right.  Then drag and drop.  This is very helpful.

Comment: Lol that's perfect wish I had thought of that 8 > )

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  Sorry if my question was very basic or vague -- I'm just an end user / weekend programmer wannabe trying to simplify life.  I can tell from your rep that you actually know what you're doing.  Wish I could combine your programming skill with my desperate need to simplify the daily chores of a desk life.

Comment: your welcome, I do freelance work on the side you could find me if you look around mac scripter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question technically is.  If you are trying to script via Safari injecting the file name into the form then it can't be done.  That's a security feature HTML has to ensure files aren't unscrupulously sent from your computer.  (It would be nice as there are many forms I'd love to script in this fashion)

If you are just trying to quickly get files to your form then the answer of thf is best.  Just keep a small window open and manually drop them there.  If you want to automate this though there's just no solution.